# how to resolve General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active. using PDO connection

Tags: mysql, pdo

While i am executing second Stored procedure with same connection statement(Using PDO), getting the below error.

=================================================

SQLSTATE[HY000]: 
General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active. Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll().
 Alternatively, if your code is only ever going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting the 
PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute.

=======================================================

This is my code in drupal

```
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, true);

$statement = $conn->prepare("CALL Odd_Get_Sport()");
$exec_result = $statement->execute();
while ($row = $statement->fetchObject()) {   
  print_r($row);
}


$statement ->closeCursor();

$statement1 = $conn->prepare("CALL Odd_Get_Sport()");
$exec_result1 = $statement1->execute();
while ($row1 = $statement1->fetchObject()) {   
   print_r($row1);
}
```

Help me on this.

Comment: Sometimes a subquery error or a subquery returning more than 1 rows can trigger this error

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit of a poor feature of PDO that's not well documented.  The closeCursor method doesn't work when the statement has executed a stored procedure.  You need to use the nextRowSet method.  Here's what I use

```
            while($sth->nextRowSet())
        {
            $sth->fetchAll();
        }
        $sth->closeCursor();
```

Answer (score -1):

Just set it to null before every prepare

```
$statement1=null;
$statement1 = $conn->prepare("CALL Odd_Get_Sport()");
$exec_result1 = $statement1->execute();
while ($row1 = $statement1->fetchObject()) {   
   print_r($row1);
}

$statement1=null;
$statement1 = $conn->prepare("CALL Another()");
$exec_result1 = $statement1->execute();
while ($row1 = $statement1->fetchObject()) {   
   print_r($row1);
}

$statement1=null;
$statement1 = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM test");
$exec_result1 = $statement1->execute();
while ($row1 = $statement1->fetchObject()) {   
   print_r($row1);
}
```